# How can I clean KIE Workbench (Wildfly 8.1)

Tags: wildfly, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-workbench

I need do clean unused KIE workbench projects and old unused artifacts of repository, I think I'm getting errors and my performance is going down because accumulating too much rubbish in reps or maybe because of deleting projects in the wrong way, there is a "clean" way to remove artifacts from repo and projects from project authoring(demo project for example)?

The only way I know to clean all is reinstall wildfly, but is not mantainable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the Maven repository is the issue, but you should be safe just deleting the files by hand. Any 3rd party jars get redownloaded from where ever they were first retrieved. Any KIE jars you have locally can be rebuilt.

Removing a project from the workbench does not remove the compiled artifacts from the Maven repository. This is why you have to go in with some sort of file explorer and hit delete yourself.

I should warn you that the problem with KIE jars is that if you rebuild them from source, they might not work 100% the same if the KIE version changed.